# Perl initialization values: "" vs q{} and 0 vs (1==2)

Tags: perl

```
my $EMPTY = q{};
use constant TRUE  => ( 1==1 );
use constant FALSE => ( 1==2 );


my $a = "";   vs my $a = $EMPTY;             
my $b = 0;    vs my $b = FALSE
```

Is there any difference as to which should be used over what?
Is it depend on certain cases?
If so, what are those cases regarding when you would want to use `my $b = 0;` over `my $b = FALSE` and vice versa?

Comment: When you want to get stuff done vs. when you want to impress your pretentious Java-programming friends?

Comment: Only use $a and $b when sorting.

Comment: @mob Perl will never impress pretentious Java-programming friends :/

Comment: In general, I find the use of `1==1` and `1==2` to denote true and false values to be a bit silly. In C, for example, those expressions are exactly equivalent to the constants `1` and `0`, respectively, and that will never change in any language calling itself "C". In Perl, there may be a difference (as [igegami's answer discusses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23373372/827263)) -- but I think that either the difference doesn't matter or there's a cleaner way to express it. You could also use `undef` for false and `1` for true.

Comment: You can use any defined, non-zero value for true. That includes "false", "0 but true", and "0E0" as unintuitive true values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `""` and `q{}` both produce a zero length string.

  ```
  >perl -MDevel::Peek -e"$_ = q{}; Dump($_);"
  SV = PV(0x306748) at 0x4c9058
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)            <--- Contains a string.
    PV = 0x4ac9e8 ""\0
    CUR = 0                       <--- Length of the string is zero.
    LEN = 16
  ```
- `0` produces the number zero.

  ```
  >perl -MDevel::Peek -e"$_ = 0; Dump($_)"
  SV = IV(0x229088) at 0x229098
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)            <--- Contains a signed integer.
    IV = 0                        <--- Contained integer is zero.
  ```
- `(1==2)` produces a scalar contain an empty string and the numerical value zero.

  ```
  >perl -MDevel::Peek -e"$_ = 1==2; Dump($_);"
  SV = PVNV(0x1fc598) at 0x259038
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (IOK,NOK,POK,pIOK,pNOK,pPOK)   <--- A signed int, a float and a str.
    IV = 0                        <--- Contained integer is zero.
    NV = 0                        <--- Contained floating point number is zero.
    PV = 0x23ca18 ""\0
    CUR = 0                       <--- Length of the string is zero.
    LEN = 16
  ```

Answer (score 4):

The `FALSE` value you created there is a copy of the special `PL_sv_no` variable inside Perl. This value is unique in being both numerically zero and stringy empty, and compares without warning using both the `==` and `eq` operators. By comparison, a normal empty string, such as created by `""` or `q{}`, will produce a warning with `==`

Comment: Nit: Not unique. Aside from copies thereof, there's `$!`, `$^E` and variables created with `dualvar`.